# Qt: QPSQL prepare doesn't work in class

Tags: qt, postgresql, qsqlquery

I tried to outsource the code for the connection to a local PostgreSQL server from my "main.cpp" file into a seperate class called "database.cpp".

The connection worked just fine, when I had the code in the "main.cpp":

**main.cpp**

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QPSQL");
QSqlQuery query(db);

qint32 declareConnection()
{
    db.setHostName("127.0.0.1");
    db.setPort(5432);
    db.setDatabaseName("postgres");
    db.setUserName("postgres");
    db.setPassword("password");

    return 0;
}

qint32 createUser(QString username, QString password)
{
    if (db.open())
    {
        db.transaction();

        query.prepare("INSERT INTO users (name, password) VALUES (?, ?);");
        query.bindValue(0, username);
        query.bindValue(1, toMD5(password));

        query.exec();
        query.finish();

        db.commit();
        db.close();
    }

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    qDebug() << "Declare Database: " << declareConnection();
    qDebug() << "Create User: " << createUser("Testuser", "Testpassword");

    return a.exec();
}
```

But after I put the functions in the "database.cpp", the prepare.query() fails every time I try to execute it.
Here's my current code:

**main.cpp**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    Database postgre;

    qDebug() << "Declare Database: " << postgre.declareConnection();
    qDebug() << "Create User: " << postgre.createUser("Testuser", "Testpassword");

    return a.exec();
}
```

**Database.h**

```
class Database : public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
explicit Database(QObject *parent = 0);

qint32 declareConnection();
qint32 createUser(QString username, QString password);

QSqlDatabase db();
};
```

**Database.cpp**

```
QSqlDatabase Database::db()
{
    return QSqlDatabase::database();
}

qint32 Database::declareConnection()
{
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QPSQL");

    db.setHostName("127.0.0.1");
    db.setPort(5432);
    db.setDatabaseName("postgres");
    db.setUserName("postgres");
    db.setPassword("password");

    return 0;
}

qint32 Database::createUser(QString username, QString password)
{
    if (db().open())
    {
        db().transaction();

        QSqlQuery query(db());
        query.prepare("INSERT INTO users (name, password) VALUES (?, ?);");
        query.bindValue(0, username);
        query.bindValue(1, toMD5(password));

        query.exec();
        query.finish();

        db().commit();
        db().close();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The declaration of the database seems to work just fine, but when it comes to the "createUser()" function, there is always that problem with the "query.prepare()" command.

The **database is open**, so that works.
Also the **transaction is in an open state**, when I check in debug.
The **prepare is false**.
The query.exec() says: **Syntaxerror at end of line LINE 1: EXECUTE ^**.
QPSQL: **Unable to create query**.
WARNING: **No open transaction**. (But was open???)

Comment: Where do you declare the query object in the second example?

Comment: Had to change the code a bit for posting here, didn't see that. The query is declared after the transaction was opened. Fixed it in my post.

Comment: You should examine `query.lastError()` immediately after the failure of `query.prepare()`. It's no use calling `query.exec()` if the prepare failed.

Comment: Since every "prepare" fails, i've tried your tip for the query that handles the recreation of the database. There, for example, the error to that is: "ERROR: Syntaxerror at 'DROP' LINE 1: PREPARE qpsqlpstmt_1 AS DROP TABLE IF EXISTS usergroups;DROP...". It's similar to the error from the createUser command....Syntaxerror at the first word of the command string.

Comment: @Endauriel are you sure, that code you show us, is an actual code, that you compile ? I ask it because 1) There's no semicolon after `query.exec()` 2) You're trying to give to `qDebug` void (the return value of `void declareConnection();`

Comment: I'm not trying to troll around here, yes. The actual code looks a bit different but would be too much to copy and paste in here. All the errors are simply made by trying to break the code down a bit. Of course there normally should be a semicolon after exec() (fixed it). The normal return value of the two functions is qint32 with status codes for the various exit scenarios....I just broke it down to void, so I don't have to past the code for that too. Of course, the qDebug() would not work with that, you are right. Will fix that to make the code valid with a return of 0....

Comment: @Endauriel: you can't prepare a `DROP TABLE` or a `CREATE USER`. From [PG doc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-prepare.html), the statement must be: _Any SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or VALUES statement_. What can't you stick to the INSERT that is in your question?

Comment: But I did also prepare the DROP TABLE and CREATE USER commands when they were in the main.cpp....that worked just fine?!? Since I copied the source code into the class-files, neither the DROP TABLE and the CREATE USER commands, nor any other command works. SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE....they are all leading to the same error while preparing, even if I created the database and the table from PGAdmin myself.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here

> void Database::declareConnection()
>   {
>       QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QPSQL");

you declared **local** variable `db` on a stack.
The decision is:

```
class Database : public QObject
{
   ...
   QSqlDatabase & db() { return m_db; }
private:
   QSqlDatabase m_db;
};

void Database::declareConnection()
{
    m_db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QPSQL");
...
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but that didn't change a thing. Still exactly the same errors.